# Kafka Connect Sink - From: Avro Topic, To: Json -> Redis

Tags: json, apache-kafka, redis, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I have an environment, I use a Kafka Connect Worker that consumes some data from an Oracle DataBase then pushes it in Kafka Topics on Avro format.

Now, I need to create a Kafka Connect Sink to consume this AVRO message, convert it to Json and then write it on Redis DataBase.

As far now, I'm only able to write on Redis the same AVRO message that I consumed from topic. I have tried to use the converters but I might be misunderstanding ther usage.

Bellow my configurations of the worker and the sink.

```
{
    "name": "SOURCE",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "transforms": "createKey, extractStr",
        "transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
        "transforms.createKey.fields": "ID",
        "transforms.extractStr.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.extractStr.field": "ID",
        "connection.url": "<>",
        "connection.user": "<>",
        "connection.password": "<>",
        "table.whitelist": "V_TEST_C",
        "schema.pattern": "<>",
        "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
        "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
        "incrementing.column.name": "CID",
        "timestamp.column.name": "TS_ULT_ALT",
        "validate.non.null": "false",
        "table.types": "VIEW",
        "retention.ms":12000,
        "poll.interval.ms": "30000",
        "topic.prefix": "TEST.",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "<>"
    }
}
```

SINK

```
{
  "name": "SINK",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "V_TEST_C",
    "redis.hosts": "redis:6379",
    "schema.registry.url": "<>",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "<>",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "insert.mode": "UPSERT",
    "delete.enabled": "false",
    "quote.sql.identifier": "never"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your Source Connector is using JSON, not Avro...

Comment: In any case, the Converter does not "convert" like you think it does (between serialization formats). It converts those types (JSON/Avro) into `Struct` and `Schema` classes that are internal to the Connect Framework, and the Sink and Source classes use those to actually read/write data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> pushes it in Kafka Topics on Avro format

That's not what you posted

```
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
```

---

In any case, you cannot store anything except Strings or Bytes using that Redis connector

[From docs](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-redis/sinks/RedisSinkConnector.html) (emphasis added)

> This connector expects records from Kafka to have a key and value that are stored as bytes or a string. If your data is already in Kafka in the format that you want in Redis **consider using the ByteArrayConverter or the StringConverter for this connector**

Therefore, using the AvroConverter is not possible as that generates a structured object, not a schema of string or bytes.

Note: JSONConverter with schemas disabled is effectively the same behavior as the String converter for dealing with JSON data. **However**, if using StringConverter with Avro data, you might end up with data like `Struct{foo=bar}`, but you still need to run an Avro deserializer at some level, so I'm not sure you actually can use Json or StringConverter with Avro topic data.

Comment: my mistake. This was one of my tests, but the actual info was using Avro. But I understand the answer. Thanks.